# iOS - Can't share to Snapchat using UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, snapchat

I'm working on a image editing app and we want to share a short message with hashtag alongside the image. It works just fine for most apps, some apps that don't support adding a message (like Facebook) just ignore it, but Snapchat just simply doesn't show up. When I removed the message completely, Snapchat shows up and works just fine.

Here's my code that makes Snapchat not show up (also doesn't work when using UIActivityItemProvider):

```
let message = "Short message, #hashtag"
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [message, image], applicationActivities: nil)
```

Here's code that doesn't share the message and makes Snapchat show up:

```
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [image], applicationActivities: nil)
```

Is there a way to make Snapchat ignore this message so that it shows up? I know this might be issue with their app, as this is the only one we found doesn't show up, but maybe there's a way to "hide" this message from Snapchat?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Do you know how to share to snapchat directly (without showing the uiactivityviewcontroller)?

Answer (score 0):

Hope the below tutorial will help you. Code available for Swift only.

[Snapchat Creative Kit iOS (Swift) - Image, Video, Sticker Sharing](https://mahmudul-razib.medium.com/snapchat-creative-kit-ios-swift-image-video-sticker-sharing-8ec8ed7e5efd)